# How to use MVVM Light Toolkit with existing non-MVVM Light Toolkit project

Tags: mvvm-light

I need to use the Surface project template for the application that I am working on but I also want to use the MVVM Light Toolkit too.  I see that I can "Add | New Item..." and choose an MVVM teamplate for a view, view model, or locator but there seems to be a few more things I need to do to wire this up beyond adding one of those and making sure I have added the reference to the mvvm assemblies.

I am in the process of trying to figure this out by studying what's gets generated when I create a MVVM Light project but I was hoping someone already had this all figured out and documented.  I know that Laurent mentioned that he was going to write this up in a blog post but I looked and could not find it.  If someone knows where I can find that post that would be killer.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

It's not too bad adding MVVM Light to an existing project.  I finally wrote up the blog post I've been meaning to, just for this situation:

http://chriskoenig.net/2010/07/02/adding-mvvm-light-toolkit-to-an-existing-project/

Enjoy!

Comment: Nice post, thank you!  That covered it.  As I mentioned, I am writing a Surface application and therefore have to use the SurfaceWindow template since things are a bit different for Surface views and so I also need to wireup the view pages as well.  I think I have that figured out but I would love to see that post when you get time.  Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, the blog post is no longer valid. Is there somewhere else to find it?

Comment: Google have cached it [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:53uSsB7DH6EJ:chriskoenig.net/2010/07/02/adding-mvvm-light-toolkit-to-an-existing-project/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk), but without the images

Comment: Darn, neither the original link nor Google's cached page exist anymore. Chris, would you be so kind as to repost this somewhere? Thanks!